# Code takes 2 minutes to paste values on another tab. How to optimize it?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've done this code on Google Script, but it's taking way too long (it completes 10-15 lines in 30 minutes. I don't know how to optimize it more. Could the size of the spreadsheet be influencing it's processing? If not, how do I change it to improve?

```
function PreenchePlanilhaFinal() {
  var App = SpreadsheetApp;
  App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MacroHelp').getRange(1,1).activate();
  var helpMacro = App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //aba que vc está ativo
  var lastLine = helpMacro.getLastRow(); 
  for (var i = 214; i < lastLine; i++){ 
    if (helpMacro.getRange(i, 17).getValue() == "") 
    {
      var regionCode = helpMacro.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); 
      var nomeAba = ""; //inicializo a variável da região
      for (var j = 1; j < lastLine; j++){ 
        if (regionCode == helpMacro.getRange(j, 20).getValue()){
          nomeAba = helpMacro.getRange(j, 21).getValue(); 
          break;
        }
      }
      var email = helpMacro.getRange(i,1).getValue(); 
      var aba = App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nomeAba); 
      aba.getRange(1,1).activate(); //ativo a aba
      var lastLineNovaAba = aba.getLastRow();
      for (var k = 1; k <= lastLineNovaAba; k++){
        if (email == aba.getRange(k, 8).getValue()){
          App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(k, 31, 1, 11).setValues(helpMacro.getRange(i, 6, 1, 11).getValues()); 
        }
      }
      helpMacro.getRange(i, 17).activate().setValue("Feito"); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. My quick-and-dirty response is that you are using `getValue()` inside the loop. `getValue` chews up time; better to get all the values BEFORE the loop, and just refer to array coordinates inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to optimise script function `PreenchePlanilhaFinal()`.

Execution time is affected by many `getValue` statements; each of these (particularly when repeated in a loop) can be quite costly. The solution is, where possible, to 1) `getValues()` once only and 2) do this outside the loop.

The following script is untested, but it demonstrates the basic methodology.

---

```
function PreenchePlanilhaFinal() {
  var App = SpreadsheetApp;
  App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MacroHelp').getRange(1,1).activate(); // get MacroHelp A1
  var helpMacro = App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //aba que vc está ativo
  var lastLine = helpMacro.getLastRow(); 

    // new line to get last column
    var lastColumn = helpMacro.getlastColumn();

    // new line to declare start line as a variable
    var startRow = 214;

    // define the range and get values
    var helpMacroData = helpMacro.getRange(startRow,1,lastLine-startRow+1,lastColumn).getValues();

    // declare aba outside the loop, and define the range and get values
    var aba = App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nomeAba); 
    var abaLR = aba.getlastRow();
    var abaLC = aba.getLastColumn();
    var abaData = aba.getRange(1,1,abaLR,abaLC).getValues();


    // note i = 0 since the values start on line 214
  for (var i = 0; i < lastLine; i++){ 

    if (helpMacroData[i][16] == "") // describe variable as array value
    {
      var regionCode = helpMacroData[i][4];// describe variable as array value
      var nomeAba = ""; //inicializo a variável da região
      for (var j = 0; j < lastLine; j++){ // set j to 0 since arrays are zero-based
        if (regionCode == helpMacroData[0][19]){// describe variable as array value
                        nomeAba = helpMacroData[j][20];// describe variable as array value
          break;
        }
      }
      var email = helpMacroData[i][0];// describe variable as array value
      aba[0][0].activate(); //ativo a aba //// describe variable as array value
      for (var k = 0; k < abaLC; k++){ set k to 0 since arrays are zero-based, also make "<" not "<="
        if (email == aba[k][7]){   // describe variable as array value
          App.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(k, 31, 1, 11).setValues(helpMacro.getRange(i, 6, 1, 11).getValues()); 
        }
      }
      helpMacro.getRange(i, 17).activate().setValue("Feito"); 
    }
  }
}
```